# FlatButton.icon's onPressed not getting called?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It looks like if I place a `FlatButton.icon` under the `body` of a `Scaffold`, then its `onPressed` almost never gets called? Are there any bugs associated with `FlatButton.icon`'s `onPressed` call?

Following is my **code:**

```
// My main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Loading(),
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Loading screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, size: 60.0),
          label: Text('press', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0)),
          onPressed: () {
            // This almost never gets called. I have to press a lot many times to get the below print statement to execute.
            print('Button pressed to go to location widget');
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Question:**
The issue is that `FlatButton`'s `onPressed` ***almost never gets called in above code***. It does get called if I press the button many times. Very strange! What am I dong wrong above? Is there something I am doing which is discouraged in Flutter?

**Environment:**

- macOS Big Sur.
- Output of running `flutter --version` is:

> Flutter 1.26.0-1.0.pre • channel dev •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 63062a6443
> (2 weeks ago) • 2020-12-13 23:19:13 +0800 Engine • revision 4797b06652
> Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-141.0.dev)

**EDIT:**
@Alwin Brauns suggested below that `FlatButton` is obsolete and to use a `TextButton` instead. This is good information but using a `TextButton` also ends up with the same problem.

Comment: I cannot imagine what is wrong with such a simple piece of code. Are there some bugs Flutter 1.26 and macOS Big Sur?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/jtkr6a/how_compatible_is_flutter_with_macos_big_sur/

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64961

Comment: Your Code worked in Dart pad and Also in a new Flutter Project for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Actually I Tried to Run your whole Code in A new Project and it Worked fine for me.*

The only *Error* which I was getting was due to this line of `code`

```
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/choose_location');
```

Since There is no Route Named `/Choose_location`, It Have to show a *Error* in that case,

Therefore I **Replaced** it with this line of `Code`

```
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
```

And It worked As Shown in Below `Image`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that correction Mukul. Something is strange on macOS with my code.

Answer (score 2):

Flat button is obsolete. Use text button instead. TextButton.icon

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks for that one

Comment: Yes. It does. Ah, flutter guys should somehow add a deprecated warning or some indication on these kinds of things. Thanks a lot a again.

Comment: Sorry. That was too fast from my side. Using a `TextButton` in the code also ends up with the same problem.
But, You have given a good piece of information still. I wonder what is wrong with such a simple piece of code I have.

Comment: Try to pack it in an InkWell, maybe that's works. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html or Gesture detector https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html